# RESTful convention to update resource by id or by type and language

Tags: c#, api, rest, restful-url

Currently my GET request by type and language can return only one document:

```
GET /documents?type=invitation&language=en

id: 50
text: "I would like to invite..."
```

What is a correct restful convention to update resource?

```
PUT /documents?type=invitation&language=en
```

?? Or maybe I should update resource only by id?

```
PUT /documents/50
```

Comment: The best way is to update by Id.

Answer (score 5):

You generally use PUT when you're updating the whole resource. Here you're just sending a subset of resource data - so you should use PATCH.

Your URL should be:

```
PATCH /documents/{id}
```

Then you have all the data you want to update in the request payload:

```
{
   "type": "invitation",
   "language": "en"
}
```

So you're now updating only one object per request and using the appropriate method and resource notation.

Comment: I expressed myself wrong. I want to update only the field "text". But as far as I understand I still need to use "id" in the url, instead of "type" and "language" - thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

> What is a correct restful convention to update resource?

Normally, you want to use the same URI to request a change to a resource that you use to retrieve a copy of it.

The motivation for this is caching - HTTP has built into it rules for [invalidating cached responses](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-httpbis-cache-19#section-4.4).   It isn't a general purpose mechanism, but rather designed to handle a few very specific cases (invalidating responses based on target URI, Location field, and Content-Location field only).

Thus

```
GET /your-resource-identifier-here
```

Suggests that edits should be made via

```
POST /your-resource-identifier-here
PUT /your-resource-identifier-here
PATCH /your-resource-identifier-here
```

---

```
PUT /documents?type=invitation&language=en
```

That is a perfectly normal choice for a request that is sending a replacement representation of the resource (think "save file").

If you are intending that the request modify only part of the document, you might consider sending a patch document as the request body and using the HTTP method PATCH.

If your representation were JSON, then your request to modify the text might look like:

```
PATCH /documents?type=invitation&language=en
Content-Type: application/json-patch+json

[{
 "op": "replace",
 "path": "text",
 "value": "your new text here"
}]
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what `/documents?type=invitation&language=en` gives back. If it is some sort of search and you expect multiple documents later, then `PUT` should update all of those documents and since it is a complete update not a partial, it does not make much sense. Using `PATCH` in this case is better, because it can do partial update even on multiple resources. If this URI is a unique identifier of this single resource, then you can use it instead of `/documents/50` or along with it. You can have multiple identifiers for the same resource.